# Stack a div below on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

Div 1 is above div 2 in my markup. On mobile devices, I need div 2 to stack above it. How?

`<div>
    <div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Your browser will load in the order of your code. I.E. placing `div2` before `div1` in your html file, it will load first. Also, `div`'s are, by default, `inline-blocks`. Therefore, they will move to the next line (div moves under the other) when placed in succession of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Only way you can do this is set them up as absolute position, 
OR
use javascript to switch their position on page load or page re-size event.